# Given a probability density function $f(x)$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$. Do we always have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-x)dx=1$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

This question here raises from change of integration in integration.

In integration we learn that we can use Jacobi to deal with integration. For example in one dimension, we have derivative as our Jacobian value. However, in probability class, we also learn that we need some kind of absolute value of the Jacobian. In other words, the absolute value of the derivative in one dimension. May I ask why there needs an absolute here?   Is it true that for probability integration in higher dimensions, there would need some 'absolute form' of Jacobian matrix ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In 1D it is easy to talk about orientated integrals. In ND it is way more cumbersome.

Comment: "Difficult integrals may also be solved by simplifying the integral using a change of variables given by the corresponding Jacobian matrix and determinant [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) "  from Wikipedia Change of variables

Comment: "In ND it is way more cumbersome" Do you mean change of variable in  integration in probability?

Comment: no orientated integrals. For example on the line you can walk from $0$ to $1$ or from $1$ to $0$. Now, imagine the many ways you can walk on the edges of a cube (and that is pretty simple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the integrals are identical
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(-x) \; dx \stackrel{(u  \ = \ -x)}{=}
\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} -f(u) \; du = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)  \; du =1
$$

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer